# Android - How to remove contact by group selection

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to delete all contacts by a determinated group.

I've created the group with `GROUP_ROW_ID = 987`

So I should delete contacts with `GROUP_ROW_ID = 987`!

I don’t know how to delete them.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't solved it yet this is how I do it. By no means do I suggest this is an effective solution. This is just the straight forward solution.

First find all contact-ids having a specific group id. Then creating a `ContentProviderOperation` for each contact to be deleted, and last apply the list of delete operations.

```
private void deletaAllInGroup(Context context, long groupId)
   throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException{
    String where = String.format("%s = ?", GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID);
    String[] whereParmas = new String[] {Long.toString(groupId)};
    String[] colSelection = new String[] {Data.CONTACT_ID};

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI, 
            colSelection, 
            where, 
            whereParmas, 
            null);

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = 
        new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    // iterate over all contacts having groupId 
    // and add them to the list to be deleted
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){ 
        String where = String.format("%s = ?", RawContacts.CONTACT_ID);
        String[] whereParams = new String[]{Long.toString(cursor.getLong(0))};

        operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(where, whereParams)
        .build());
    }

    context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(
        ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operations );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a record

To delete a single record, call {`ContentResolver.delete()` with the URI of a specific row.

To delete multiple rows, call `ContentResolver.delete()` with the URI of the type of record to delete (for example, `android.provider.Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI`) and an SQL WHERE clause defining which rows to delete. (Caution: Be sure to include a valid WHERE clause if you're deleting a general type, or you risk deleting more records than you intended!).

```
Be careful with deleting Contacts! Deleting an aggregate contact deletes all constituent raw contacts. The corresponding sync adapters will notice the deletions of their respective raw contacts and remove them from their back end storage.
```

---

```
Specify READ_CONTACTS and WRITE_CONTACTS permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml.
```

---

Iterate through each contact and delete each record: [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

[Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html)

Comment: Ok but my problem is find the right contact and i cant find a field that tell me the contact is in a determinated group. For what 've seen i've to look the group table and get the id of people in it but i fail in it :D so... how do i match the 2 table? is there a way to join them?? ty

Answer (score 0):

```
private final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id=b.other_id WHERE b.property_id=?";

db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(propertyId)});
```

[rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

**another example where I join two tables in one query**

```
private static final String JOIN_QUERY=
 "SELECT * FROM Employee JOIN User ON userId = employeeUserId";
```

Comment: So... which field match them? I've seen that ContactsContrat have many sub table and i suppose all the table have a key that match a contact, but i dont understand which... the first table is SELECT * FROM view_groups and the second is SELECT * FROM view_raw_contacts_restricted WHERE (1)... where do i get the contact? >.<"